# Does J2ME support HTML5?

Tags: html, java-me, lwuit, midp, midlet

I want to make an application for J2ME phones.

In that application I want to use HTML5,
how I can do this?

I worked on LWUIT. Does LWUIT support HTML5?
Or give me any other browser info.

Comment: J2ME, or low end feature phones, generally don't not support HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

LWUIT/[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) support HTML5 but not on J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in HTML5 (or any HTML version, for that matter) parser or renderer in J2ME. There's some sort of HTML viewer support in the LWUIT library, but I suspect it is reasonably limited in general, and also in particular regarding specifically HTML5 support. In any case, research LWUIT and see if it is enough for your needs or not (hard to say without knowing your real/actual requirements).

It is also not very practical to write your own HTML parser and renderer (especially if you also need to be able to handle CSS and JavaScript). In essence, you'd have to write your own complete web browser in J2ME.

You can, of course, use platformRequest() to launch the default browser, but not that many mobile phones have HTML5 support yet.

If you also manage the server-side (where the HTML5 pages come from), and all you really need is the data, then write the server code to return/send the data to your J2ME MIDlet as either XML or JSON, which are much easier to handle.